# Panasonic Tough Pad Tablet detection using React or JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a camera functionality in Desktop and Tablet. I need to detect the device first and then add camera functionality.

I have detected Device using navigator-user-agent but when I try it in windows or tablet, It is detecting as windows only:

```
enter const webcam_Result = (sync () => {
  try {
    var has_webcam = await detecting_Webcam();
    if (has_webcam === true) {
      var detect_Device = navigator.userAgent;
      if (detect_Device.includes("Windows")) {
        this.setState({
          webcam_access: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ webcam_access: false });
      }
    }
    if (has_webcam === false) {
      this.setState({ webcam_access: false });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("entered into catch block");
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
};
```

Expected Results : need to differentiate desktop and tablet using navigator.useragent

Comment: `return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") ||(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
};` Use this to see if the device isMobile

Comment: Thank you for reply.

I am able to detect a mobile device , I need to detect a Panasonic tablet device.
navigator.userAgent is returning "Windows" even for tablet device instead of "Tablet"

navigator.useragent output for "Tablet" Device : User-agent header sent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36